# Synchronize file access from different kernels?

Tags: files-and-directories

Let's say we have two different notebooks `note1.nb` and `note2.nb` performing calculations on two different kernels simultaneously. Both of them need to access and write to a file `file.txt`. However, clearly they cannot write to the file simultaneously, so each should implement a waiting loop for as long as `file.txt` is being used by the other notebook. To do that, we need a way to determine in Mathematica whether `file.txt` is currently being used or not.

Therefore, my question is:

> Is there a function in Mathematica that determines whether a file is currently being used by a different process? (By a different Mathematica kernel in particular?)

Perhaps there is some convenient workaround way of determining that?
Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: I don't think there's a way to check this, but you could try an `OpenAppend` to `WriteString` without danger of overwriting. Obviously this is unsatisfying and might lead to some weird race conditions or something, though.